# Serenity-Platform - Order Details tab is not taking Order ID

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, serenity-platform

I am trying to create the same example of Orders- Order detail.

[image]

I did it on my custom module which is Contract and Contract Line item.

[image]

[image]

The problem is when you are adding contract line item from contract dialog, on save event, **Contract Id(which is the foreign key) is null**, it is not deriving automatically from parent table Contract.

[image]

Any idea please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sample has all of details for this. Compare your code

Comment: thanks victor for your reply, I followed the same sample/codes on Order-order detail and applied it on my custom module but the foreign key is not auto populating. Any detailed step by step guide? maybe i missed something.

Comment: Is this MasterDetailRelation is available in free version?

Comment: It's in northwind module, so yes it's included in community version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need override your save behavior in contract repository for create identity. Try set field in this override.

```
    private class MySaveHandler : SaveRequestHandler<MyRow> 
    {
        protected override void SetInternalFields()
        {
            base.SetInternalFields();
            Row.OrderID = yourId;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks victor, yes i can override the save behavior in contract line item repository but how can I retrieve the master record id(contract id)?. I checked the order-order detail sample, order detail repository save behavior was not overridden but it is working fine, how it happens?

Comment: Serenity has magic :) 

`MasterDetailRelationBehavior` is auto runs on `OnAfterSave`. It's extends `OnAfterSave` method for save relation. So if you create your `Id` on `OnBeforeSave`, it's must auto get this id `OnAfterSave` too. You can check your `Id` field on row with create an override `OnAfterSave` and call `base.OnAfterSave();` then hit the breakpoint. Your `Id` must be on your `this.Row`.

Comment: Here is where and how to master details gets the Id value.

https://github.com/volkanceylan/Serenity/blob/360c8e04a08927490f9172beafbdde89e8a49d66/Serenity.Services/RequestHandlers/IntegratedFeatures/MasterDetail/MasterDetailRelationBehavior.cs#L331